# Iron IO ignores retry time limit (Laravel + Iron IO)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, queue, iron

I am using Iron IO's push queues with Laravel 4.1 to queue a job that takes a long time (4-5 minutes) to run.  My problem is that Iron IO retries the job before the job has finished running (ie. the job takes so long to run that Iron IO thinks it has failed, and retries it).

Attempted solutions:

1. Iron IO has settings on its push queues for when it should retry a job.  I have it set to 1 retry (the minimum allowed) with a retry wait time of 500 seconds (which is more than enough time for the job to complete).  HOWEVER, Iron persists in retrying the job after only 60 seconds (which the default retry time), ignoring its current setting of 500 seconds.
2. I have tried using $job->delete() and $job->attempts() in my worker to signal to Iron that the job is complete, but neither have worked.  My worker code is below.

   ```
   class Worker {

       public function fire($job, $data)
       {

           if( $job->attempts() > 1 )
           {
               $job->delete();
           }
           else
           {
               // perform job that takes 4-5 minutes
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Earlier I had simply

   ```
   class Worker {

       public function fire($job, $data)
       {

            $job->delete();

          // perform job that takes 4-5 minutes

       }
   }
   ```

   But that did not work either.

Essentially, I want Iron IO to wait for 10 minutes before retrying the job, but failing that I will be happy if it just never retries it.

Comment: Only possible way (as I see it) is using the IronMQ PHP Client and use the setProgress($percent, $message) method to tell your worker that the your job has some progress. When the new worker is fires, get the jobs details and see if there is any progress.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I guess I'll start familiarizing myself with the Client

Comment: I believe this is because you need to respond with a 202 for long running jobs using Push Queues: http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/push_queues/#long_running_processes__aka_202s Not sure how Laravel deals with that.